# Postgres returned row fails not null check

Tags: postgresql

I'd really like to know why the `IF (previous_foo IS NOT NULL)` condition fails below, given that changing this line to `IF (previous_foo.total IS NOT NULL)` evaluates true.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_total(the_bar bar)
 RETURNS numeric
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 STABLE
AS $$
      DECALRE
        previous_foo foo;
      BEGIN
        previous_foo := foo_previous(the_bar);

        IF (previous_foo IS NOT NULL) THEN -- fails
        -- IF (previous_foo.total IS NOT NULL) -- works
          return previous_foo.total;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
      END;
$$;
```

So how can `previous_foo` be null, yet `previous_foo.total` not be null :/

Previous foo is doing something like this FYI

```
create or replace function previous_foo(the_bar bar) returns foo
    LANGUAGE sql STABLE
    AS $$
      SELECT foo.* FROM foo 
        WHERE -- conditions;
$$;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is conforming to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) and the SQL standard:

> If the *expression* is row-valued, then IS NULL is true when the row expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null, while IS NOT NULL is true when the row expression itself is non-null and all the row's fields are non-null.

Must be that some field in the composite is NULL.

This is not the only strange ruling of the standard committee when it comes to NULL…

Comment: Thanks, Yes ok this makes some "sense".  Some of the fields in that row are null.